# Foreign key mapping inside Embeddable class

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship, composite-key, embeddable

I am using `eclipselink` for `JPA`. I have an entity, which has a **composite key** fabricated out of two fields. Following is my **Embeddable** primary key class' fields(members).

```
    @Embeddable
    public class LeavePK {
       @ManyToOne(optional = false)
       @JoinColumn(name = "staffId", nullable = false)
       private Staff staff;
       @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
       private Calendar date;
       //setters and getters
    }
```

My entity is going to hold leave data related to a staff, so I am trying to combine staff object and leave date to produce composite key. Apart from my logic, it is not allowing me to have a foreign key mapping inside embeddable class. When I try to use *JPA tools--> Generate Tables From Entity*, it gives error as below, which explains, but I am not getting it.

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The mapping [staff] from the embedded ID class [class rs.stapp.entity.LeavePK] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [leavePK] from the source [class rs.stapp.entity.Leave]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.
```

Does it mean, I cannot have a key(from composite key) which is also a foreign key. Is there a alternative way to accomplish this ERM? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't put relationships into ID classes, neither for `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` ones. An `@Embeddable` class may only include the annotations `@Basic`, `@Column`, `@Temporal`, `@Enumerated`, `@Lob`, or `@Embedded`. Everything else is provider-specific syntax (e.g. Hibernate allows this, but since you're using EclipseLink, which is the JPA RI, I doubt this is what you want).

Here's an example JPA PK/FK mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Zips")
public class Zip implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private ZipId embeddedId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "iso_code")
    private Country country = null;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ZipId implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    ...
}
```

HTH

Comment: This is only correct for JPA 1.0, since then JPA 2.0 has allowed references in Embeddables.