# Getting org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unexpected nested component on the referenced entity when mapping a @MapsId

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

```
I have a table structure like that :- 

    @Entity
@Table(name = "Load_Container_Tray")
public class LoadContainerTray {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LoadContainerTrayPK loadContainerTrayPK;

    @MapsId("loadContainerPK")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "dest_ebu_nbr", referencedColumnName = "dest_ebu_nbr"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "outbound_load_id", referencedColumnName = "outbound_load_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "dest_ebu_cntry_code", referencedColumnName = "dest_ebu_cntry_code"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ctnr_trackg_id", referencedColumnName = "ctnr_trackg_id") })
    @ManyToOne
    private LoadContainer loadcontainer;
}
```

@Embeddable
public class LoadContainerTrayPK implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3392075534159950245L;

@Basic
private LoadContainerPK loadContainerPK;

@Column(name = "load_unit_id", columnDefinition = "char(32)")
private String loadUnitId;
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "load_container")
public class LoadContainer {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LoadContainerPK loadContainerPK;

    @MapsId("loadDestinationPK")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "dest_ebu_nbr", referencedColumnName = "dest_ebu_nbr"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "outbound_load_id", referencedColumnName = "outbound_load_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "dest_ebu_cntry_code", referencedColumnName = "dest_ebu_cntry_code") })
    @ManyToOne
    private LoadDestination loadDestination;

    @Column(name = "row_nbr")
    private short rowNumber;
}

@Embeddable
public class LoadContainerPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3392075534159950245L;

    @Basic
    private LoadDestinationPK loadDestinationPK;

    @Column(name = "ctnr_trackg_id")
    private String containerTrackingId;
}
```

public class LoadDestination {

```
@EmbeddedId
    private LoadDestinationPK loadDestinationPK;

    @MapsId("outboundLoadId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "outbound_load_id", referencedColumnName = "outbound_load_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private OutboundLoad outboundLoad;
```

}

```
@Embeddable
public class LoadDestinationPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3548089581858405303L;

    @Column(name = "outbound_load_id")
    private String outboundLoadId;

    @Column(name = "dest_ebu_nbr")
    private Integer destinationId;

    @Column(name = "dest_ebu_cntry_code")
    private String destEbuCntryCode;

}
@Entity
@Table(name = "outbound_load")
public class OutboundLoad {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "outbound_load_id", columnDefinition = "char(30)")
    private String outboundLoadId;

    @Column(name = "load_id")
    private int loadId;
}
```

When i am trying to deploy application on TOMEE server, i am getting this error :-

" org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unexpected nested component on the referenced entity when mapping a @MapsId: com.walmart.move.nim.outdoc.entity.LoadContainer: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unexpected nested component on the referenced entity when mapping a @MapsId: com.walmart.move.nim.outdoc.entity.LoadContainer .

Can someone please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: can you please provide the  `OutboundLoad` class

Comment: @osamayaccoub i have added OutboundLoad class also. Please look into it.

Comment: @osamayaccoub i have edit the chain relationship. problem is with LoadContainerTrayPK which is having PK to LoadContainerPK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should annotate 
`private LoadDestinationPK loadDestinationPK;` in `LoadContainerPK` with `@Embedded` instead of `@Basic`, why are you annotating it with `@Basic` and how will this class be mapped as a Basic type ?

Comment: I tried to change from Basic to Embedded. but it is showing me compile time error :- Attribute "loadDestinationPK" has invalid mapping type in this context.

Comment: which version of JPA are you using ?

Comment: we are using hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final   and i am using this <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0-6</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency> .      for all JAVA ee features.

Comment: try to  turn off validation for this in Eclipse under `Window -> Preferences -> Java Persistence -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Attributes -> Cannot resolve attribute name` .. as per  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106124/eclipse-error-on-mapping-with-embeddedid

Comment: also try adding `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` explicitly on `LoadDestinationPK ` ... Annotating nested embedded class with this explicitly (though it's the default) is sometimes the solution

Comment: i tried doing this :- @Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class LoadDestinationPK implements Serializable { along with turning off ) . Still getting the same error while deploying code on tomee . Even i am not able to change from Basic to Emebedded. it throws me same error saying " Attribute "loadDestinationPK" has invalid mapping type in this context"

Comment: " Attribute "loadDestinationPK" has invalid mapping type in this context" at compile or runtime, and did you try removing eclipse validation while adding `@Embedded` ?

Comment: error is at compile time only. yes i removed eclipse validation also