# Getting the "Java class for mapped type is a member class" on nested class in Eclipse/JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I use a code generator which generates a nested class, roughly as follows:

```
package generated;

@Entity(name = "Items")
@Table(name = "ITEMS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Items
    implements Equals, HashCode
{

    protected List<Items.Item> item;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Items.Item.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ITEMS_HJID")
    public List<Items.Item> getItem() {
        if (item == null) {
            item = new ArrayList<Items.Item>();
        }
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Items.Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    // ...

    @Entity(name = "Items$Item")
    @Table(name = "ITEM")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public static class Item
        implements Equals, HashCode
    {
        // ...        
    }
}
```

[Full source code](https://pastebin.com/4zhGr4Sg).

I'm getting the following error in Eclipse:

> The Java class for mapped type "`Items$Item`" is a member class

The error is marked on the `@Entity(name = "Items$Item")` line.

What does this error mean and what can I do about it?

My roundtrip tests (save entity to the database, load, compare to the original) work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar issue and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106124/eclipse-error-on-mapping-with-embeddedid): The [JPA Spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1575375451_d2e596d5e61ebfe2e3de05b56c7d548f) says that mapped member classes are **not officially supported**. Therefore, Eclipse complains that the class `Item`is defined within `Items`.

Since the code works with the JPA implementation you are using, you can **turn off** the error message in Eclipse: `Window -> Preferences -> Java Persistence -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Type -> Mapped Java class is a member class`.

Your code generator does not comply with the JPA specification.